# How to apply the string() function to each attribute?

Tags: xpath, xmllint

I need to grab some hyper references in a Bash script.

The following command uses `curl` and `xmllint` to read all `href` attributes of a HTML page:

```
curl --silent -L google.com | xmllint --html --xpath '//a/@href' -
```

But I need only the values of the attributes. The value of an attribute can be selected with the `string()` function. But if I use it, I get only the first element of the list of attributes:

```
curl --silent -L google.com | xmllint --html --xpath 'string(//a/@href)' -
```

How can I apply the the `string()` function to each attribute?

Comment: with xpath 2 it would be `//a/@href/string()`, but it is not available in xmllint (yet)

Answer (score 0):

You could do (notice the difference in the XPath expression):

`curl --silent -L google.com | xmllint --html --xpath '//a/@*'`

and then add another pipe to send the output to `sed`, filtering out the attribute names to get the values you want. But this is a sort of odd way to extract stuff from a document.

Comment: Why should I send more attributes than the hrefs to sed? BTW I use already a sed workaround, but doing so makes it hard to handle nested single and double quotes correctly. And I would like to get a better XPath based solution.

Comment: Nevermind about the additionall attributes -- I guess I was confused by the wording of your question. If you want a better solution, I highly recommend writing a quick Python script to do what you want to do here instead of using xmllint (which I would say is not great in this context). Let me know if you'd like to see some sample code to get started.

Comment: I don't know Python and I think on the Solaris 10 server I have to use Python might be unavailable.

Comment: What about Perl or something like that? Anything with a more sophisticated XML API than ``xmllint``?